# html, css border dissappear when changing border-collapse

Tags: html, css, border

I have created an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FX9WR67VWKXT) to illustrate my issue as well as this fiddle

**Fiddle example:**:

```css
table,
tr {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#table1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: blue;
}

#table2 {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>border-collapse: collapse:</h2>
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lois</td>
      <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>border-collapse: separate:</h2>
  <table id="table2">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lois</td>
      <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm wondering why my row border disappears when the `border-collapse` is set to separate.

If you change `tr` to `td` in the style section, you can see that when I have a border around every cell, it does not disappear.

Comment: `border: 3px solid red;`  override by the     `border-collapse: separate;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS specification says that row borders are ignored in this mode:

> Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups cannot have borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border properties for those elements).

[Link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders)

Comment: Is there no way to overcome this>